# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, oauth, java-17

Recently I have upgraded to Spring Boot 3 and Java 17. Below is my buid.gradle file.

```
ext {
        springBootVersion = '3.0.2'
        springCloudVersion = '2022.0.0-M3'
    }

implementation ('com.okta.spring:okta-spring-boot-starter:2.1.6'){
        exclude group: 'com.nimbusds', module:'oauth2-oidc-sdk'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', module:'spring-web'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.security', module:'spring-security-oauth2-client'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.security', module: 'spring-security-oauth2-core'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.security', module: 'spring-security-web'

    }

  implementation ('org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client:5.8.1'){
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.security', module: 'spring-security-oauth2-core'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.security', module: 'spring-security-web'
        exclude group:  'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core:6.0.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.auth', name: 'google-auth-library-oauth2-http', version: '1.3.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.auth', name: 'google-auth-library-oauth2-http', version: '0.25.5'
    implementation group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client', version: '1.33.3'
    runtimeOnly 'com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:10.3'

    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core:6.0.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:6.0.0'
```

And my local Websecurityconfig class as below.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@Profile({"local", "default", "test"})
public class WebSecurityConfigurationLocal {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

When I did a ./gradlew clean build -x test (Skipping teste) the build is successful. But when I run the unit and integration tests it gives the below error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/max/network/student/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurationLocal.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'filterChain' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotiationStrategy' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAuthorizedClientRepository' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'authorizedClientRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authorizedClientRepository' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'authorizedClientService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authorizedClientService' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception with message: Could not initialize class org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration$Builder
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check `clientRegistrationRepository` is annonated with `@Repository` and your `springBootClass` can find `clientRegistrationRepository` using `@EnableJpaRepository` annonation.

Example:-

```
@Repository
public interface AuthorityRepository extends JpaRepository<Authority, Integer> {}

And 
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "test.com")
public class SpringApplication{
SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.class, args);
}
```